# QgsVectorFileWriter creating layer with unexpected WKB type

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing, qgis-2.18

I'm trying to use a vector file writer and I'm getting an unexpected WKB type of my output layer.

I'm setting up the writer like this

```
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter( output_layer, 'UTF-8', fields,  QgsWKBTypes.PointZM , inlayer.crs() )
```

Below is information about my QGIS installation at the time.

[image]

When I check the properties of the shapefile that is generated, the geometry type is showing up as PointZ instead of PointZM. The simple script below should duplicate the problem.

```
##input_layer=vector
##output_layer=output vector

from qgis.core import *
from qgis.utils import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *

inlayer = processing.getObject(input_layer)
provider = inlayer.dataProvider()
fields = provider.fields()
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter( output_layer, 'UTF-8', fields, QgsWKBTypes.PointZM, inlayer.crs() )
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry(QgsPointV2(QgsWKBTypes.PointZM, 1, 2, 3, 4)))
writer.addFeature(feature)
del writer
```

It may be easier to test this in the python console with the following commands

```
>>> writer = QgsVectorFileWriter('c:/test/test_layer.shp', 'UTF8', QgsFields(), QgsWKBTypes.PointZM, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'))
>>> feature = QgsFeature()
>>> feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry(QgsPointV2(QgsWKBTypes.PointZM, 1, 2, 3, 4)))
>>> writer.addFeature(feature)
True
>>> del writer
```

Just make sure you have a test folder on the C drive and then you can add the generated shapefile to QGIS to inspect.

Comment: Which GDAL version is your QGIS based off? (you can check in the help->about dialog)

Comment: @ndawson I added a screenshot of that dialog just in case any of the other versions would be important.

Comment: is strange because the same thing occurs using MultiPointZM,the result shapefile is MultiPointZ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interestingly, if you do not use `del writer` and check the metadata for the layer, it is still registered as a PointZM type (but the feature is not added).

I just tested the code you provided for use in the Python Console and can't say what the reasoning for this is but an alternative could be to first create a **memory layer**, populate this with your QgsPointV2 and then write this to a shapefile and force the WKBType as a PointZM:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import QVariant

mem_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Point?crs=epsg:3857", "name", "memory")
provider = mem_layer.dataProvider()
provider.addAttributes([QgsField("FID", QVariant.Int)])
mem_layer.updateFields() 

feat = QgsFeature()
feat.setGeometry(QgsGeometry( QgsPointV2(QgsWKBTypes.PointZM, 1, 2, 3, 4)))
feat.setAttributes(["0"])
provider.addFeatures([feat])

QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat(mem_layer, 'c:/test/result.shp', "utf-8", None, "ESRI Shapefile", layerOptions=['SHPT=POINTZM'])
```

---

Example:

[image: Example]

---

*Tested on QGIS 2.18.13 for Win7 64-bit.*

---

**Edit:**

As [@TJ Rockefeller](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/56050/tj-rockefeller) already mentioned in his comment, there's no need to create a memory layer. You can force the geometry type for the output to be *PointZM* by adding the following layer creation option:

```
layerOptions=['SHPT=POINTZM']
```

So the code could look like:

```
writer = QgsVectorFileWriter('c:/test/result.shp', 'UTF-8', QgsFields(), QgsWKBTypes.PointZM, QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem('EPSG:3857'), layerOptions=['SHPT=POINTZM'])
feature = QgsFeature()
feature.setGeometry(QgsGeometry(QgsPointV2(QgsWKBTypes.PointZM, 1, 2, 3, 4)))
writer.addFeature(feature)
del writer
```

Comment: It looks like you don't need the memory layer to get this to work. It looks like the magic is in `layerOptions=['SHPT=POINTZM']`. I added that to the definition of my QgsVectorFileWriter, and everything works now in the examples that I gave.

Comment: @TJRockefeller - Yes, you're right! Thanks for checking, edited post to reflect your comment :)