# Create new MultiPolygon with PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, polygon-creation, multipart

I want to create a new MultiPolygon shapefile, I tried this code

```py
Mp_Layer = QgsVectorLayer('MultiPolygon?crs=EPSG:26191', 'layer', 'memory')
QgsProject.instance.addMapLayer(Mp_Layer)
```

But when I check the `wkt_geom` if the created shapefile its gives a polygon type.

It’s possible to create a `Multipolygon` directly by PyQGIS?

Comment: The layer is type polygon but the geometry stored in it can be multipolygon, which indicates the geometry has multiple parts, either exterior rings or interior rings (holes). Although https://qgis.org/pyqgis/3.4/core/QgsVectorLayer.html indicates that the memory provider can have type “point”, “linestring”, “polygon”, “multipoint”,”multilinestring”,”multipolygon” I suspect, without digging too deep into the source code, that linestring = multilinestring and polygon = multipolygon for the constructor (point != multipoint - special case) in keeping with OGC standards for geometry storage.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i want to know if i can change the geometry Type from Polygon to MultiPolygon or create a new shapefile file as MultiPolygon. That because i have already made many function based on Wkt of MultiPolygon type.

Comment: I had similar issues with shapefiles being created with the wrong wkt. https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/259762/56050 I was using the QgsVectorFileWriter, and I'm not sure if it's related, but there may be some info there that may be helpful.